# send multiple (key value) in one transmission (all SAME sensor)?

Tags: mqtt

i'm designing for having 100s of IoT devices. each broadcasts once a day, sending 20 data points, e.g. ALL these readings are from ONE gas meter over 24 hours. this is NOT telemetry from various sensors; one device, one sensor, 24h of data, all 20 readings sent in one shot, all at once, in one STRING. is there a way to split this 20-value set into TWENTY MQTT messages? we don't have the bandwidth nor battery power to send 20 messages when one will do.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The payload of a MQTT message is just a collection of bytes, you can pack any data structure you want into it.

If you want to send one message a day with something like a CSV list of readings then that it totally up to you.

Comment: thanks, I already know that. Is there way to, so to speak, unpack it? Make it useful? If the list of values in the nosql database and what you can do with it provide the value. It appears you can do this with thingspeak.

Comment: That's not what you asked in the original question. There are 1000's of ways to do it, but since you've not mentioned where/how you are subscribing to the data we have absolutely no way of answering.

Comment: what's one of those ways? for now, we're subscribing to data using thingsboard. this won't be the meat of what we'll do once we understand both the platform AND our data. the goal is to have automated rules deal with the data and almost never look at it onscreen. 

Tempted to simply create a webserver that takes POSTed data, splits it, then persists to SQL or key-value. the data will then be examined by rules which then add to a (same?) queue that other rules will look at. we built rule-based medical systems like this, back in the day. is there any general purpose systems available? thanks!